# Flask set_response for domain (not just subdomain)

Tags: python, cookies, flask

So when users of my site visit a.mysite.com, my flask server is setting the browser in their cookie via:

```
@app.route('/safe')
def tag_browser():
  response = redirect('/')
  response.set_cookie('hello', 'world')
  return response
```

This sets the cookie for **a.mysite.com**. However, I am interested to set the cookie for **mysite.com**

There is this thread: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139) which talks about how I can achieve the same effect wth

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com
```

My problem is, how can I do so inside flask?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `set_cookie` function can get `domain` as param. From the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/):

```
set_cookie(key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/', domain=None, secure=None, httponly=False)
```

> domain – if you want to set a cross-domain cookie. For example,
>   domain=".example.com" will set a cookie that is readable by the domain
>   www.example.com, foo.example.com etc. Otherwise, a cookie will only be
>   readable by the domain that set it.